# asp.net text returns null values when button is pressed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create registration form and every time I click the submit button the properties that i used always returns a null value therefore once data in the database shows empty rows

HTML code for the buttons and formatting:

```
    <div class="tab-2 resp-tab-content" aria-labelledby="tab_item-1">
<div class="facts">
<div class="register">
<form action="#" method="post">
 <asp:TextBox ID="txt_emailreg" runat="server" placeholder="Email Address:" type="text" required="" EnableViewState= "false"></asp:TextBox>                     
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_passwordreg" runat="server" placeholder="Password:" type="password" required="" EnableViewState= "false"></asp:TextBox>                                                 
 <asp:TextBox ID="txt_fName" runat="server" placeholder="First Name:" type="text" required="" EnableViewState= "false"></asp:TextBox>                                       
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_lName" runat="server" placeholder="Last Name:" type="text" required="" EnableViewState= "false"></asp:TextBox>                             
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_contactNumber" runat="server" placeholder="Contact Number:" type="text" required="" EnableViewState= "false"></asp:TextBox> 
<asp:RadioButton ID="rbtn_Male" Text="Male" runat="server"/>
<asp:RadioButton ID="rbtn_Female" Text="Female" runat="server"/>

<div class="sign-up">
<asp:Button ID="btn_register" runat="server" Text="Register Account" type="submit" OnClick="btn_register_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false" data-dismiss="modal" />
<input type="submit" value="Create Account"/>
  </div>
 </form>
  </div>
   </div>
   </div>
```

c# code:

```
public string RegisterEmail
{
    get { return txt_emailreg.Text; }
    set { txt_emailreg.Text = value; }
}

public string RegisterPassword
{
    get { return txt_passwordreg.Text; }
    set { txt_passwordreg.Text = value; }
}

public string FirstName
{
    get { return txt_fName.Text; }
    set { txt_fName.Text = value; }
}

public string LastName
{
    get { return txt_lName.Text; }
    set { txt_lName.Text = value; }
}

public string ContactNumber
{
    get { return txt_contactNumber.Text; }
    set { txt_contactNumber.Text = value; }
}

public string Gender
{
    get
    {
        if (rbtn_Female.Checked)
        {
            return "F";
        }
        else if (rbtn_Male.Checked)
        {
            return "M";
        }

        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }

    set
    {
        if (value == "F")
        {
            rbtn_Female.Checked = true;
            rbtn_Male.Checked = false;
        }
        else if (value == "M")
        {
            rbtn_Female.Checked = false;
            rbtn_Male.Checked = true;
        }
    }
}

 protected void btn_register_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection connAccount = new SqlConnection(connString);
            connAccount.Open();

            string sqlInsertStatement = @"insert into accountsTB values ('" +
                                               RegisterEmail + "','" +
                                               RegisterPassword + "','" +
                                               FirstName + "','" +
                                               LastName + "','" +
                                               ContactNumber + "','" +
                                               Gender + "')";

            SqlCommand cmdTxt = new SqlCommand(sqlInsertStatement, connAccount);
            cmdTxt.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connAccount.Close();
            connAccount.Dispose();

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
}
```

Comment: in webforms you can access your controls in your click method and just use  `.Text` for TextBox and `.Value` for RadioButton (e.g. `txt_emailreg.Text` for `RegisterEmail`)

Comment: don't forget to use post back on button and form, otherwise it will vanish the data. also, out validations before actually submitting the  records to db as a best practice

Comment: are you setting the value of these tetboxes on pageload?

Comment: i am not setting the values on pageload

Answer (score 1):

In your Question you have posted code for the button click event , but never specified anywhere about where you are assigning the  values to the variables in your method , please find a sample how you need to assign the textbox values to your local variables

`RegisterEmail = txt_emailreg.Text;`

Comment: sorry i forgot to include my properties .

Comment: @mffa why do you want to save them as properties, because the problem you are encountering is when you enter the value in the `text-box` .  the properties will get that value only when you do postback, then only you can able to retrieve the values into the properties values.

Comment: how do i apply a postback?